# How to implement BigQuery for the Google EKM?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-kms

I want to implement BigQuery which interacts with an external key management using **HYOK** function.

I have not found any guides about the configuration of BigQuery with **EKM** (and then using HYOK) but just the configuration of it with the **CMEK** (that use BYOK).

Can someone here help me?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify some of the terminology in your question,

- [HYOK](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/hold-your-own-key-with-google-cloud-external-key-manager) = Hold your own key = The ability to use keys outside GCP from within GCP
- [Cloud EKM](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm) = Cloud external key manager = Cloud EKM is the service that GCP uses to implement HYOK.  Cloud EKM is used through the Cloud KMS API.  EKM keys have the `EXTERNAL` [protection level](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/ProtectionLevel) in Cloud KMS.
- [CMEK](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/cmek) = Customer managed encryption keys = The ability to use keys in Cloud KMS to protect data at rest in other GCP services (such as BigQuery).

Answering your question directly, [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption) applies equally to **all** keys available through Cloud KMS, including Cloud EKM keys.  The difference for using a Cloud EKM key as opposed to one stored inside GCP is in how you set up the key in the Cloud KMS API (see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/ekm-internet)).  Once it is set up, the Cloud EKM keys work the same as other protection levels.